# Shared objects in a clustered application with Liberty Profile cluster on BlueMix

Tags: cluster-computing, ibm-cloud, websphere-liberty

I am developing an application that needs to be clustered in Liberty Profile on BlueMix. I need to have a shared List of objects accessible to all nodes of the cluster. The app will perform update, add and remove operations on them, as one node does not cope with the big load need of the application. How can I do this with Liberty Profile? Is there a best practice or recommended approach before looking for 3rd party solutions for this? Thanks

Comment: Edit: I have read some documentation and distributedMap seems to be the IBM library to solve this issue, but I am not sure how to configure it to work in a clustered application deployed in BlueMix Liberty. Thanks for any information and example on this.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking at the services in Bluemix, for example Data Cache or Redis. An external (to your app) service would be the [cloud best practice](http://12factor.net/backing-services) for sharing data between multiple instances of the same application or multiple applications that need to communicate.

A traditional Liberty cluster doesn't make sense in Bluemix because the Cloud Foundry platform upon which it is based is already providing ways to achieve high availability and scale.

Comment: Thanks. I will test Redis Cloud.